# Can't figure out the best way to loop through

Tags: wordpress

I have some of parent pages in Wordpress that I am trying to list in the following way:
There are 10 parent pages using the same page-template
First I need to list them by title in the nav tabs section
Second I need to display their content and list their respective child pages in each tab content section
At the moment I am just calling them by ID individually. Is there a way to create a loop somehow using the page-template.

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" id="pageTabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#one">Parent Page title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#two">Parent Page title 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#three">Parent Page title 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#four">Parent Page title 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#five">Parent Page title 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#six">Parent Page title 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#seven">Parent Page title 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#eight">Parent Page title 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#nine">Parent Page title 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#ten">Parent Page title 10</a></li>
</ul>



<div class="tab-content responsive">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="one">content and children 1</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="two">content and children 2</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="three">content and children 3</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="four">content and children 4</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="five">content and children 5</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="six">content and children 6</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="seven">content and children 7</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="eight">content and children 8</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="nine">content and children 9</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="ten">content and children 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page template's filename is stored as a post meta with key '_wp_page_template', so basically you can use get_post_meta($post_id, '_wp_page_template', true); to get the template filename for the page with ID $post_id.

You can also do the reverse (i.e. getting id from page template filename) using [Custom Field Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in WP_Query or other wordpress functions.